# Does the Asus Transformer have any USB ports?

Tags: usb, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Does the Asus Transformer have any USB ports? I know that the available keyboard dock has 2 USB ports, but does the tablet itself have any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not. The only USB ports are on the keyboad dock. The tablet itself has:

- A microSD card slot
- A mini HDMI port
- A 40-pin docking/charging/USB transfer connector
- An audio jack

Source: [CNet's review of the ASUS Eee Pad Transformer](http://reviews.cnet.com/tablets/asus-eee-pad-transformer/4505-3126_7-34467853.html?tag=rnav#reviewPage1)